# How can I essentially stop my VB program until a valid value is entered via Text Box?

Tags: vb.net

How can I work around an invalid/null value entered into a text box?

Basically I have a simple program I need to develop to solve a simple quadratic equation:

```
Public Class Main

    Private Sub btnHelp_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHelp.Click
        UserGD.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtStepX.Text = ""
        lstResult.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGo.Click
        Do
            txtStepX.Text = InputBox("Please enter a valid value for x!", "Oops!", "")
        Loop While String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStepX.Text)

            Dim stepx As Single
            Dim X As Single
            Dim y As Single
            stepx = txtStepX.Text
            Dim result As String

            For X = -5 To 5 Step stepx
                y = (3 * (X) ^ 2) + 4
                result = ("x = " & X & " >>>>>>>>>> y = " & y)
                lstResult.Items.Add(result)
            Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the part I want to focus on:

```
    Do
            txtStepX.Text = InputBox("Please enter a valid value for x!", "Oops!", "")
    Loop While String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStepX.Text)

            Dim stepx As Single
            Dim X As Single
            Dim y As Single
            stepx = txtStepX.Text
            Dim result As String
```

The above manages to check the text box (after its text value is changed by the Input Box) and loops fine, as long as it is empty... However, say I put a letter in, say, "l", it crashes and Visual Studio gives me the error "Conversion from string 'l' to type 'Single' is not valid." - which is fair enough. Although, I assumed the Null in `isNullorEmpty` meant it would catch invalid values, such as strings when it's supposed to be single.

I've tried quite a few things, and even my Computing teacher has been trying to get a solution.

I can't remember most of the things I've tried thus far so if I'll give whatever you guys come up with a go just to be on the safe side!

**Update**
Although not the clearest of code - here is what I found works the best for my needs:

```
    'Written by a very tired and frustrated Conner Whiteside
    'With his own blood.
    'And sweat.
    'And tears.
    'Lots of tears.
    '28/10/2014

Public Class Main

Private Sub btnHelp_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHelp.Click
    UserGD.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtStepX.Text = ""
    lstResult.Items.Clear()
End Sub
' On Go button click
Private Sub cmdGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGo.Click
    'Checks if Text Box value is a number
    If IsNumeric(txtStepX.Text) Then
        'Declares variables if Text Box value is in fact a number
        Dim result As String
        Dim stepx As Double
        Dim X As Double
        Dim y As Double
        'Displays error message with a re-input opportunity if previously entered number is out of range.
        Do While txtStepX.Text <= 0 Or txtStepX.Text > 10
            'InputBox simply changed the value of the TextBox's Text. MUST be an InputBox or there will be nothing to break the loop.
            txtStepX.Text = InputBox("The step size for the x values must not be a negative number or above 10." & vbCrLf & "Please enter another number for the step size of the x values.", "Oops!")
            'Covers an Empty input given that IsNumeric does not. This can also prevent crashing if the 'Cancel' or 'X' is pressed on InputBox.
            If txtStepX.Text = "" Then
                'Exits Sub Class in order to avoid running mathematical operations (below) with a string "". Effectively allows a 'reset'.
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        'After all checks, sets Text Boxvalue to variable stepx
        stepx = txtStepX.Text
        'Loops the solving of the equation from x = -5 to x = 5 with the specified step size.
        For X = -5 To 5 Step stepx
            'sets the answer of the equation (y) to variable y.
            y = (3 * (X) ^ 2) + 4
            'concatenates a string in the required format.
            result = ("x = " & X & " >>>>>>>>>> y = " & y)
            'Adds the result to the List Box before repeating the process for the next value of x.
            lstResult.Items.Add(result)
        Next
        'Catches any non numeric inputs in the Text Box or the Input Box e.g "l".
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(txtStepX.Text) Then
        'Displays error message before ending If statement and Sub Class, allowing the user to return to the start and try another input. - No Input Box or Exit Sub needed.
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid number for the step size of the values of x.", 64, "Oops!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Honestly wouldn't have gotten anywhere if it weren't for your efforts!

Comment: I am a bit rusty on Visual Basic, but if you do "Dim stepx As String" and dim X and Y as String as well, does that fix it? I suspect that you are having a problem when it tries to convert from a string to "Single" on "stepx = txtStepX.Text"

Comment: @Jonathan If I declare it as a String it can't carry out any mathematical operations (y = 3x^2 + 4), but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply check if the input is numeric.

```
       If IsNumeric(txtStepX.text) then
          // Your statements
       Else 
          // MsgBox("Please enter a number")
       End if
```

However, it will accept something like 3.5.4

A more complicated solution would be to limit the characters from being entered by checking on each keypress,

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
      If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
          //Statements here
      Else
        e.Handled = True
      End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: YES! That's it! Thankyou! I can sleep tonight knowing I have that sorted now... lol
I've never covered the IsNumberic Condition, but then again, I've hardly covered anything in my course thus far. This will be extremely useful in the coming months! Thanks again Cody!

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you use the Double type instead of Single - it won't make any difference to how fast your program runs, but it will reduce rounding errors a lot.

Second, you can use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if a string can be parsed as a Double value. `IsNumeric` has some quirks which you do not want to find out about.

I took the liberty of adjusting the text which is shown to the user, as an "Oops!" before they have even tried to enter a value might be confusing, and it is better to tell them a number is needed than "a valid value":

```
Dim stepx As Double
Dim inp As String = ""
Dim inputTitle As String = "Number required"
Do
    inp = InputBox("Please enter a number for x:", inputTitle)
    ' change the input box title to indicate something is wrong - if it is shown again.
    inputTitle = "Oops!"
Loop While Not Double.TryParse(inp, stepx)

txtStepX.Text = stepx.ToString()
```

Comment: So what can I do with a variable declared as Double? I've only ever seen it in value conversion errors e.g. Conversion to type 'Double' is not valid.
The Input Box was only title "Oops!" as it is only called if the initial value in the text box (which is the primary method of inputting the value) was null (or now, not numeric).

Comment: With a variable declared as `Double`, you can do everything that you can with a `Single` *and* it will be more accurate in calculations. It isn't obvious from the code that you showed that that the InputBox is only used if needed. I would have expected something like `If Not Double.TryParse(txtStepX.Text, stepx) Then ~code to show the InputBox~` to be there ;)

Comment: Yeah, the code isn't very clear without the form - plus I have overlapping variables as the Text Box and Input Box are the same thing. I put in the Input Box as it gave me a chance to change the value of the Text Box before the Loop came around again, which was a big part of my problem before, so it's all really messed up and unprofessional lol I'll maybe try and tidy it up a lot more towards the end of the development but for now, I just want it to be functional.